# Discord JS - Bot status disappears after some time

Tags: discord.js

My bot status doesn't show after a while, I think my **setPresence** is misplaced in the code, but if so, I don't know where to put it

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is now online ✅');
    setInterval(checkWebsiteAndNotify, 10000);

    client.user.setPresence({ activities: [{ name: `Status Servers`, type: ActivityType.Watching }] }, { status: 'online' });
});
```

I tried to put it in

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["1793"] });
```

But it didn't work either, in this part it doesn't show it at all

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the presence inside the "`ready`" event. Please don't do that!

Instead, specify your presence in your **client** constructor:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, ActivityType } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds], // up to you
    presence: {
        activities: [{
            name: 'You',
            type: ActivityType.Watching
        }],
        status: 'online'
    }
});
```

And please don't use "magic numbers" for intents, refer to [the guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html) related to intents.

Answer (score -1):

You should place the `setPresence` method inside the `ready` event listener.

Here's the correct placement:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS", "GUILDS"] });

// ...

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot is now online ✅');
  setInterval(checkWebsiteAndNotify, 10000);

  client.user.setPresence({ activities: [{ name: `Status Servers`, type: 'WATCHING' }] }, { status: 'online' });
});

// ...
```

Comment: Sorry stackoverflow to delete part of my code for no reason, that's exactly what I have, however the bot no longer displays its status after a while

Comment: Answer is wrong, question states the same code.